# Mercurial/Kiln: Compare local with remote, separate repositories?

Tags: mercurial, kiln

I'm pretty newbish at this...

1. I had a zip file on my Harddisk of many sourcecode files.
2. I unzipped it and have worked on some of the files. I have now 'init'd a repository in the folder. (Obviously it believes there are no changes because it's just been init'd)
3. I've extracted the zip file (1) into a REMOTE repository.
   How can I compare the LOCAL (2) with the REMOTE (3) repository? (Am I pushing/cloning/pulling? etc)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Your current problem is that the two repositories don't share a history and mercurial doesn't know that the different versions of a file are actually the same file.

If I was in your situation, here's what I'd do (and I'd back up any current work first!):

1. `init`, `add`, and `commit` the remote repository
2. `clone` that remote repository locally
3. using the filesystem, copy your local code folder onto the local repository
4. `diff` to make sure that the changes you copied onto the repo are what you expected.
5. `commit` those changes as your first changeset
6. `push` those changes to the remote repository .

Then you're all set to `commit` (N times), `pull`, `merge`, `push`, and repeat.

Alternatively, if all you need is to know what has changed, I'd recommend just diff-ing the two folders using a utility like kdiff3 or Beyond Compare 3.